# Exclude attribute in @BadgerFish in RESTEasy

Tags: jakarta-ee, rest, resteasy, pojo

I am going to make one WebApplication which is RESTful. I am using RESTEasy API for that. I am using @BadgerFish annotation for mapping with POJO in POST request.  But I have some attributes which should not allow to come in parameter. So my problem is how can i exclude those attributes or how to prevent @BadgerFish to set those values come in parameter?

For instance:

My DataBase info:
Table Name: `user`
Fields : `name->String, loginCoung->int`

My POJO:

```
@BadgerFish
public class POJO{
private Stirng name;
private int loginCount = 0;


public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
public void setName(String nm) {
        this.name= nm;
    }
public int getLoginCount() {
        return loginCount;
    }
public void setLoginCount(int loginCount) {
        this.loginCount = loginCount;
    }   
}
```

My RESTFul code:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/user")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postUser(@BadgerFish POJO p) {      

        System.out.println("post req.....");
        return Response.status(200).entity("sucess"+p.getLoginCount()).build(); 
    }
```

JSON Data comes in POST Request:
Case 1: if JSON is -> {"name":"abc"} 
Response will be 0 (Works as expected)
Case 2: if JSON is -> {"name":"abc","loginCount":"12"}. It should not set the value of loginCount in POJO obj. and Response should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about just overriding 'setLoginCount()' to take whatever action is needed (like setting a secondary flag or such)?